# Uninstall Webpart from Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

How can I uninstall a Custom Webpart from Sharepoint Server 2010?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can manage webparts from:

- Central Administration

  - System Settings

    - Manage Farm Solutions

      - Select the WebPart

and click "Retract Solution".

Answer (score 0):

Use PowerShell commands to add/remove or upgrade solution///

Adding Solution

```
Add-SPSolution PATH
```

Deploying solution

```
Install-SPSolution SolutionPackage.wsp –WebApplication servername –GACDeployment
```

Uninstalling solution

```
Uninstall-SPSolution SolutionPackage.wsp –WebApplication servername
```

Removing solution

```
Remove-SPSolution SolutionPackage.wsp

Install-SPSolution –Identity $solutionName  -Webapplication $webapplication -GACdeployment
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add link related with the question. Beytan Kurt is right but if you try to add a new web part in your page you will notice there in the Category section it still have reference to the web part. This link which I post it will give you a full explanation why the web part still have reference into Category section. Also it will help you to fully remove the web part from your farm solution. This is the [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/44120/after-retracting-webpart-solution-webparts-still-showing-up) .

Best Regards, 
Stefan Chonov

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to retract solution both by Central Administration and by Power Shell due the following error:

> Uninstall-SPSolution : Admin SVC must be running in order to create
>   deployment timer job.

The retract was being scheduled but not executed at all.

So, I opened the SharePoint Power Shell as administrator and typed the following command after schedule my retract:

```
stsadm.exe -o execadmsvcjobs
```

This command force all the admin scheduled jobs to be executed, so the retract worked good. It works for install and uninstall a web part. Good luck.